# Read array from firebase once and put it into an array

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database

How to read firebase array and put it into swift array? I'm trying to solve this problem for like 4 hours. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
ref.child("names").child("myNames").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if let item = snapshot.value as? String {
            namesArray.append(item)
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code looks fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't `as? String` be `as? [String : Any]`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen array stays empty, even when i wait for a minute and print the array using a button

Comment: @EDUsta if i change it to `as? [String : Any]`  i get an error: Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: @articga You should iterate the dictionary and push the values to the namesArray. Is that [String], right?

Comment: @EDUsta I'm not a professional, please can you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse the snapshot as `[String : Any]?` and fetch the values in the dictionary.

```
ref.child("names").child("myNames").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    if let itemDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
        for (key, value) in itemDictionary {

            // Another check for String
            if let valueString = value as? String {
                namesArray.append(valueString)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to unwrap an array of `String` as a single `String`, so that is why it's failing.  Change to the following:

```
ref.child("names").child("myNames").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    if let item = snapshot.value as? [String] {
        namesArray = item
    }
}
```